# Как сделать сторону блока таким прозрачным css?

Tags: css

Чёт не получается, такое сделать подскажите как примерон такое делается спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью [Mask Image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image)

```css
#c {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-mask-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
    mask-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}

#p {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div id="p">
    <img src="https://developer.mozilla.org/files/3537/linear-gradient.png" id="c" />
</div>
```